# Getting <figure> size to match enclosed <image> size

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie at html and css.  I'm trying to set up a header, in a responsive page.  I wrapped an  with  and  tags.  I can resize the image using percentages in CSS, but the outer figure wrapper continues to keep the width of the original image and won't change.  I tried setting the same percentages on the  element, too, but to no avail.  Even tried another image and it did the same thing.  Dev tools give me no hint of what's making this happen.  Thanks for any help!

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: #173873;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

header .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 0;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo img {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}

.nav-title h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-title h6 {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #173873;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="container">

    <div>
      <figure class="logo">
        <a href="">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/800/800" alt="Parakaleo"></a>
      </figure>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-title">
      <h1>Parakaleo</h1>
      <h6>Bookkeeping</h6>
    </div>

    <nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </nav>

  </div>
  <!-- End of container -->


</header>
<!-- End of header -->
```